# Generar un dropdownsearch a partir de una lista de objetos en flutter

Tags: flutter

Estoy tratando de hacer un DropDownSearch en flutter, es decir, un campo de selección con busqueda para un formularo. Para ello estoy utilizando la dependencia [dropdown_search](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_search)

El objetivo es que me muestre la variable "name" contenida en una lista de objetos de la siguiente clase:

```
class Farmer
{
  int? id;

  String? createdAt;
  String? updatedAt;

  String name;
  String city;
  String email;
  int phoneNumber;
  String description;

  Farmer({
    this.id,
    this.createdAt,
    this.updatedAt,
    required this.name,
    required this.city,
    required this.email,
    required this.description,
    required this.phoneNumber,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap(){
    return{"id":id,
      "createdAt":createdAt,
      "updatedAt":updatedAt,
      "name":name,
      "city":city,
      "email": email,
      "phonenumber": phoneNumber,
      "description":description};
  }
```

Actualmente, estoy tomando como base el siguiente ejemplo de la documentación:

```
DropdownSearch<Farmer>(
                                    popupProps: PopupProps.menu(
                                      showSearchBox: true,
                                      showSelectedItems: true,
                                      disabledItemFn: (Farmer farmer) => farmer.name.startsWith("i"),
                                    ),
                                    items: model.fvm.farmerList,
                                    dropdownDecoratorProps: const DropDownDecoratorProps(
                                      dropdownSearchDecoration: InputDecoration(
                                        disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                        hintText: "dropdownCityName",
                                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.black,
                                          fontSize: 12,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    onChanged: print,
                                    selectedItem: (Farmer? farmer) => farmer.name,
                                    itemAsString: (Farmer farmer) => farmer.name,
                                  )
```

Donde en la lista "items" mostraría la variable "name" que me interesa, hasta ahí todo bien, ya que tengo una lista de tipo `List<Farmer>` de la que puedo generar otra lista con los nombres para pasarselos a "items".
Sin embargo lo que necesito no es guardar el nombre, si no el campo "id" de la clase en la base de datos, y esto es en donde ya me pierdo. Puesto que no sé como capturar esa ID.

Por otro lado, el "hinttext" no se muestra, esto tampoco se porque sucede.

EDIT:
Tratando de poner en práctica la primera solución propuesta, estoy teniendo un problema rarísimo a la hora de generar la Lista con el Map, dejo el código:

```
Future<void> generateFarmerSelection() async
   {
     List<Farmer> farmerList = [];

     setState(ViewState.Busy);
     farmerList = (await fvm.getFarmersList())!;
     setState(ViewState.Idle);

     print(farmerList[0].name);
     for (int i= 0;i<farmerList.length;i++)
     {
       Map<String,dynamic> farmer = {"name": farmerList[i].name,"id":farmerList[i].id};

       farmers.add(farmer);
     }

   }
```

La linea;

```
farmerList = (await fvm.getFarmersList())!;
```

me da un error tal que:

```
A value of type List<Farmer>  can't be assigned to a variable of type List<Farmer>
```

Donde la función getFarmerList() devuelve un List y se asigna a otro List, así que no veo donde puede estar el problema.
Por otro lado, el edito me sugiere hacer un:

```
(await fvm.getFarmersList()).cast<Farmer>();
```

Pero no da resultado.

En otra parte del código tengo una asignacion exactamente igual y si me funciona de la forma:

```
(await fvm.getFarmersList())!
```

EDIT2: Conseguí arreglar el problema de la siguiente forma:

```
var farmerList = (await fvm.getFarmersList());
```

Por alguna razón hay que ponerle tipo var

Comment: Es raro el error, intenta validando que la lista del await fvm.getFarmersList() no esté vacia y luego de esto haces un for para agregar esos elementos a la nueva lista

Comment: Vacía no está, de hecho si consigo compilarlo a través del cast, puedo saber que tiene un numero x de elementos, pero de esa forma no me deja acceder al contenido de los elementos, dando error de cast invalido. Tendría que agregar esos elementos a una nueva lista y despues recorrer dicha lista para agregarlos a la lista de map?

Comment: intenta:  await fvm.getFarmersList().then((value) { if(value.isNotEmpty) {setState((){ farmerList = value; }) }}), esto si es que de la función asíncrona retornas una lista de tipo Farmer

Comment: Lo conseguí solucionar (Ver EDIT2), solo me queda una última pregunta, y es como podría ponerle un valor inicial, de cara a que cuando edite el formulario se vea lo que seleccioné anteriormente.

Comment: El dropdownButtonSearch tiene una propiedad que se llama selectedIndex, tendrías que crear una variable aparte de tipo Map<String, dynamic> y rellenar esta variable con el dato que guardaste en la base de datos, actualizaré el código de mi respuesta para que veas.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, conseguí solucionar el problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tambien estoy trabajando con el widget dropdownsearch.
Te dejo mi metodo para que veas si puede ser de ayuda, espero que si. :)

Primero que todo te mostrare un ejemplo utilizando los datos de 'tipo_contrato' que debo rellenar en mi formulario. Obtengo los datos desde mi apiRest de la siguiente forma

en mi archivo 'tipo_contrato_service.dart'

```
Future<void> getActivos() async {
var url = Uri.parse(ConexionServidor.tipoContrato + '/');

try {
  var respuesta = await http
      .get(
    url,
    headers: await AuthService().headers(),
  )
      .timeout(
    Duration(seconds: ConexionServidor.timeOutSecond),
    onTimeout: () {
      return http.Response(
          'Error', 408); // Request Timeout response status code
    },
  );
  if (respuesta.statusCode == 200) {
    final json = jsonDecode(respuesta.body);
    tipoContratoDopdownSink(json['respuesta']);
  }
} catch (e) {
  LoadingStatus.timeOut();
}
}
```

la respuesta de consulta vendria siendo algo como esto:

```
{
"respuesta": [
    {
        "nombre": "Plazo Fijo",
        "estado": true,
        "creado_por": "6298c399ca914bbb51bb164f",
        "fecha_creacion": "02-06-2022",
        "id": "629903bd7b29df5225a9ac36"
    },
    {
        "nombre": "Indefinido",
        "estado": true,
        "creado_por": "6298c399ca914bbb51bb164f",
        "fecha_creacion": "02-06-2022",
        "id": "629903c37b29df5225a9ac3a"
    },
    {
        "nombre": "Fijo a Tiempo Parcial",
        "estado": true,
        "creado_por": "6298c399ca914bbb51bb164f",
        "fecha_creacion": "02-06-2022",
        "id": "629903d87b29df5225a9ac42"
    },
  ],
}
```

todo esto lo almaceno dentro de un stream que esta ubicado en el mismo archivo de la siguiente forma:

```
  final _tipoContratoDropdownControllerStream=
  StreamController<List<dynamic>>.broadcast();

   Function(List<dynamic>) get tipoContratoDropdownSink =>
  _tipoContratoDropdownControllerStream.sink.add;

   Stream<List<dynamic>> get tipoContratoDropdownStream =>
  _tipoContratoDropdownControllerStream.stream;

  void disposeStream() {
     _tipoContratoDropdownControllerStream.close();
  }
```

gracias a esto ahora cualquier nuevo registro que se realice mientras realizo mi formulario podra reflejarse en el 'tipoContratoDopdownStream'.
luego lo muestro en mi formulario de la siguiente forma:

```
StreamBuilder(
              stream: TipoContratoService().tipoContratoDropdownStream,
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                  case ConnectionState.waiting:
                    return const Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.amber, strokeWidth: 1));
                  default:
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      List<String> data = [];
                      for (var item in snapshot.data) {
                        data.add(item['nombre']);
                      }
                      return DropdownSearch<String>(
                        dropdownSearchDecoration:
                            CustomInputs.formInputDropdownDecoration(
                                label: 'Tipo de Contrato'),
                        mode: Mode.MENU,
                        showSelectedItems: true,
                        showSearchBox: true,
                        items: data,
                        selectedItem: usuarioFormProvider.tipo_contrato,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          for (var item in snapshot.data) {
                            if (item['nombre'] == value) {
                              usuarioFormProvider.tipo_contrato =
                                  item['nombre'];
                            }
                          }
                        },
                      );
                    } else {
                      return Container();
                    }
                }
              },
            ),
```

Para finalizar, como se puede apreciar arriba en la funcion OnChange() se realiza un for in de los datos obtenidos y por mediante de la comprobacion del seleccionado se puede manipular los demas datos del objeto como sea requerido.

Answer (score 1):

Una solución sencilla sería en la propiedad `onChanged` guardar el id de la opción seleccionada en una variable creada por si, supongamos que la variable creada es la siguiente:

```
int? idDropdown;
String? nameDropdown;
```

En el la propiedad `onChanged` le asignas el valor:

```
onChanged: (value) {
  if(value != null && value.isNotEmpty){
    setState(() {
       idDropdown = farmer.id;
       nameDropdown = farmer.name;
    })
  }
}
```

Un ejemplo tomando en cuenta tu código sería este:

```
 DropdownSearch<Map<String, dynamic>>(
        dropdownDecoratorProps: const DropDownDecoratorProps(
          dropdownSearchDecoration: InputDecoration(
            disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
            labelText: 'Nombre de la ciudad',
            hintStyle: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 18,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        popupProps: PopupProps.menu(
          showSearchBox: true,
          disabledItemFn: (Map<String, dynamic> e) =>
              e["nombre"].toString().startsWith("I"),
        ),
        items: const [
          {"nombre": "Brazil", "id": '1'},
          {"nombre": "Italia(Disable)", "id": '2'},
          {"nombre": "Tunisia", "id": '3'},
          {"nombre": "Canada", "id": '4'}
        ],
        itemAsString: (Map<String, dynamic> e) => e['nombre'],
        onChanged: (e) {
          if (e != null && e.isNotEmpty) {
            print(e!['id']);
           }
        },
      ),
```

La única diferencia es que yo utilizo una lista de mapas y cada mapa tiene su id.

//EDIT:

Para rellenar el `dropdownButtonSearch` es necesario implementar la propiedad `selectedItem` para ellos vamos a crear una variable de clase de tipo `Map<String, dynamic>`

```
Map<String, dynamic>? selectedItem;
```

Supongamos que tienes una función donde haces el llamado a la base de datos para rellenar los campos del formulario y poder editar

```
Future<void> funcionObtenerDatos() async {
  //peticion http, etc, etc
  //validas que la información guardada del combo no sea nula
  // no se cuales sean tus campos asi que me invento
  if(dropdownValue.isNotEmpty){
    selectedItem = dropdownValue;
  }
}
```

Asi es como se estaría llenando el `dropdownButtonSearch` y finalmente le asignas la variable a la propiedad `selectedItem`:

```
DropdownSearch<Map<String, dynamic>>(
        dropdownDecoratorProps: const DropDownDecoratorProps(
          dropdownSearchDecoration: InputDecoration(
            disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
            labelText: 'Nombre de la ciudad',
            hintStyle: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 18,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        popupProps: PopupProps.menu(
          showSearchBox: true,
          disabledItemFn: (Map<String, dynamic> e) =>
              e["nombre"].toString().startsWith("I"),
        ),
        items: const [
          {"nombre": "Brazil", "id": '1'},
          {"nombre": "Italia(Disable)", "id": '2'},
          {"nombre": "Tunisia", "id": '3'},
          {"nombre": "Canada", "id": '4'}
        ],
        selectedItem: selectedItem,
        itemAsString: (Map<String, dynamic> e) => e['nombre'],
        onChanged: (e) {
          if (e != null && e.isNotEmpty) {
            print(e!['id']);
           }
        },
      ),
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, he seguido tus consejos pero he tenido otro problema, edito la pregunta principal.